# 7zip self extracting installer erases files before installation completes

Tags: installation, wix, 7zip, self-extracting

We made a new installer that works pretty well using Visual Studio and WIX.  Now I'm trying to zip it up and make a self extracting installer for distribution.

I can create the installer.exe just fine, and it runs.  The installer starts, but it fails.

I think this is because the 7zip exe is deleting the files before the installer has a chance to use them (we are running setup.exe to start the installer).

I have searched all over, but can't find any hints about how to make this work.  Am I missing an option for 7zip?

The creation line:

```
7z a myInstaller.7z installer/bin/release/*
copy /b \program files\7-zip\7zsd.sfx config.txt myInstaller.exe
```

Config.txt is

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="My Title"
RunProgram="Setup.exe"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

There is a workaround on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/3731985c-d9cc-4403-ab7d-992a0971f686 (about 7/8 down by Phylliss), but that seems creaky.  Is that really the only way to make this work?

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue. On XP machines, part of the install works fine, but sometimes the temp files are gone if the machine decides to reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell immediately by your sample what's wrong with it. However, here's what I used to build 7z self-extracting archive and it worked well, deleting the files only after the installation is over.

The config file:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="My Installer"
InstallPath="%temp%\\Temp_Installation"
RunProgram="setup.exe"
Delete="%temp%\\Temp_Installation"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

The creation script (NAnt):

```
<exec program="${_7z.exe}" workingdir="${path}\SFX">
  <arg line="a -y -r ${path}\setup.7z" />
  <arg line="${paths.build.to7z}\*.*"/>
</exec>

<exec program="cmd.exe" verbose="true" workingdir="${path}\SFX">
  <arg value="/C" />
  <arg line="copy /b 7ZSD_All.sfx + ${config} + ${path}\setup.7z" />
  <arg file="${paths.build.sfx}\setup.exe"/>
</exec>
```

Hope this helps you finding the source of your problem. You might also check that you use the most recent version of 7z SFX module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

My testing showed that if I switched to using 7zSD_ALL.sfx AND added the InstallPath and Delete keys to the config, it worked without the batch file.

Comment: And, now it isn't working consistently.  Sometimes it works, and others, not so much.  As in, the same exe works on one computer, and not another.  The files still seem to be getting deleted before they can be used.  We are testing under Win 7 - I wonder if older WindowsInstaller versions leave setup.exe running longer.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, when i omit the Delete:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="My Installer"
InstallPath="%temp%\\Temp_Installation"
RunProgram="setup.exe"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```